# How to rename order shipments name in customer dashboard frontend?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order, dashboard

I am using Magento 2.1
I want to rename order shipments name and switch order shipments first then invoice.
[image]

Comment: You should enable debug hint in backend to override theme like this

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145276)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to override this file in your module

Path: `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_info_links.xml`

> Following is the code for that invoice and order shipment links in
>   customer account dashboard if you want to swap just swap the block or if you want to rename the Order shipment label just rename the label order shipment block

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Link" name="sales.order.info.links.invoice">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">Invoices</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/invoice</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Invoices</argument>
                </arguments>
</block>
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Link" name="sales.order.info.links.shipment">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">Shipments</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/shipment</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Shipments</argument>
                </arguments>
 </block>
```

**I hope this will help**